# Creating a const with JS for background url to change background

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, background-image

I have a button and I want to be able to change the background of my html file via the button click, and then again change back to original URL when clicked again.

So I created a map with key/values. First key will be original background, and it's value will be the new background. And opposite with the second key/value pair.

Below is my code

```
    const nextBackgroundImageUrl = {
        "url('../images/pexels_bg.jpeg')" : url('/images/bbyshrk.jpg'),
        "url('../images/bbyshrk.jpg')" : url('/images/pexels_bg.jpeg')
        }


function changeImg() {

    const currentBackgroundUrl = elem.style['background-url'];

    elem.style['background-url'] = nextBackgroundImageUrl[currentBackgroundUrl];

}
```

It seems this should work? Except, I am getting an error in the console:

```
index.html:197 Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined
```

in reference to the VALUE of the second key/value pair,  url('/images/pexels_bg.jpeg')

This file definitely exists.

Is it that URL cannot be used as a value to a key? Or am I missing something else.

Any advice helps, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here the url in value is getting considered as a variable. Change it to a string

```js
const nextBackgroundImageUrl = {
  "url('../images/pexels_bg.jpeg')": "url('/images/bbyshrk.jpg')",
  "url('../images/bbyshrk.jpg')": "url('/images/pexels_bg.jpeg')"
}
```